# Plasma, Fourth State of Matter, and Magnetic Fields and Electric Fields

Tags: electricity, magnetism

Plasma is the fourth state of matter consisting of positive atoms, and freed negative electrons.  Does plasma have an electric field, and magnetic field?

Comment: You know there's Physics SE? Why you posted it here? And what do you mean by "having" fields?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for physics.SE.

Answer (score 1):

There is not necessarily a preexisting magnetic or electric field in a plasma, since the charges can be randomly distributed. Think of plasma as similar to a metallic state conductor -- a sea of mobile electrons (and, of course, ions in plasma, so perhaps it better approximates a semiconductor, with electrons and holes). A plasma in thermal equilibrium, not exposed to an external electromagnetic field, should be uncharged.

That said, unbalances occur for a number of reasons. For example, electrons are thousands of times less massive and therefore more mobile than ions, so [charge separation occurs, leading to a plasma potential.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)#Plasma_potential). [Lasers can generate a charged plasma, accelerating particles](http://newscenter.lbl.gov/2014/12/08/world-record-for-compact-particle-accelerator/) with the [wakefield effect.](http://www2.mpq.mpg.de/lpg/research/LWFA/LWFA.html)